# Is SObject Constructor signature supported in Iluminated Cloud?

Tags: illuminatedcloud

I'm wondering is SObject constructor signature supported in IC? When I use this syntax, IC marks it as `Unresolvable method or constructor signature` error. Do I miss something in config?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is supported. I'm not sure why this is being flagged. Post your issue on the [IC forum](https://groups.google.com/a/illuminatedcloud.com/forum/#!forum/qanda) so Scott can look into this with you. Remember to state the version of IC you are using.

NB: It could be that you have an out-of-date Offline Symbol Table, so try updating this before you post your query.

Comment: This is my question on the IC forum - https://bitbucket.org/RoseSilverSoftware/illuminatedcloud/issues/1466/constructor-not-defined-error-for-sobject

Comment: Ah, not on the forum but as an issue. Fair enough.

Comment: Now I know there is a separate **forum** for IC. My bad, I didn't check the link in your answer being confident that it points to the repo's issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

The other thing to try if Illuminated Cloud is behaving oddly is to use Webstorm's "Invalidate Caches/Restart" function. On Mac, that's under the File menu.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/cleaning-system-cache.html

An out of date Offline Symbol table is a common problem. The Webstorm cache is less common, but still worth a punt if you're getting inexplicable error messages.

Comment: Nope, didn't help. Anyways, thanks for your suggestion.