# Do I really have to cast to SObject in DML in Illuminated Cloud?

Tags: illuminatedcloud

When I do a DML operation on a specific type, Illuminated Cloud reports it as error:

[image]

Is the upcasting to SObject is the only option here?

EDIT:

Variable name is not the issue.

[image]

Comment: bottom line, if it compiles OK, then it is an IC2 false positive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. I suspect this is a false positive message due to IC's Apex parser not being able to distinguish between the type "Account" and the variable "account" (remember that Apex is actually case insensitive).

Try doing something like:

```
Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test');

insert acc;
```

And see if the warning goes away. (I'm not saying this is good, and you probably should post your issue on the [IC forum](https://groups.google.com/a/illuminatedcloud.com/forum/#!forum/qanda) so Scott can respond/fix the issue.)

**UPDATE**

Given that a name change still shows this issue, I suspect it is that your Offline Symbol Table is out of date (and relates directly to your [other posting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283902/is-sobject-constructor-signature-supported-in-iluminated-cloud/283908) here). Make sure you update the OST and reload the project to see if this issue disappears.

Comment: +1 for the IC forum. Scott is really quick in terms of turnaround.

Comment: agree - false positive (and this isn't the only one). If you give Scott a reproducible and simple use case; he'll fix it quickly

Comment: Variable name is not the cause. See the updated question. I will definitely post it to the IC forum.